# Unable to share attached hard drive with samba

Tags: media-server, permissions, samba, networking

I've been looking at a number of different tutorials for sharing my attached external hard drive over my network, and can't seem to get any to work. Currently I have /home/pi accessible from my windows machine, but I can't seem to get anything else. When I plug in the external HD to the pi, its contents are available under /media/The Jolly Roger. I have tried putting the following in /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[share]
path = /media
```

however that doesn't make it available

In addition, when I type the command sudo chown -R pi:users /media/'The Jolly Roger' and hit enter it doesn't take it, it instead goes to a new line and then every time I hit an arrow key it outputs ^[[X. [Not sure what this means.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk0L8.png)

I'm relatively inexperienced with Linux, so there might be something obvious that I am not aware of. Thanks.

What I'm looking at:

http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/

Comment: have you tried the chown command with the quotes around the whole path like this sudo chown -R pi:users "/media/The Jolly Roger" Also note you are sharing media but only chaining the subdirectory. You probably want to do this instead sudo chown -R pi:users /media. It would also help if you post the samba.conf

Comment: The ^[[X etc means the shell is expecting something else before it executes the command. Most likely seen with a missing closing quote. The resolution as @SteveRobillard notes is to ecase the entire path in double quotes.

Comment: I've tried double quotes and it still does the same thing.

Comment: What happens if you rename the directory and remove the spaces (either use underscores, hyphens or run the words together with camel case). In Linux they often cause more problems than they solve. FYI if you don't include the @username we won't be notified of new comments.